# How to unescape unicode inside a string

Tags: python, python-unicode

My code loads the title of a youtube video.

I have problem with accented and special characters

For Example: i'm getting this title in string format: `LES \\xc9TUDES DE M\\xc9DECINE`

I need to remove the double backslash to get `LES \xc9TUDES DE M\xc9DECINE`

So i can be able to print it correctly in python 3:

```
print(`LES \xc9TUDES DE M\xc9DECINE`)
>>LES ÉTUDES DE MÉDECINE
```

Thank you

Comment: That's not *removing*, that's *unescaping*...

Comment: What python version are you using, how exactly are you getting your string? What exactly is the type of the object you are working with? `str` or `bytes`?

Comment: Thanks, changed the title. I'm using 3.5, i'm sure it's a string object

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I un-escape a backslash-escaped string in python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python) Spoiler alert: `bytes(s, 'utf8').decode('unicode_escape')`

Comment: It would help if you actually used valid Python literals next time...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `literal_eval` function like so:

```
Python 3.6.0 (v3.6.0:41df79263a11, Dec 23 2016, 08:06:12) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license()" for more information.
>>> import ast
>>> ast.literal_eval("'LES \\xc9TUDES DE M\\xc9DECINE'")
'LES ÉTUDES DE MÉDECINE'
```