# How to programmatically convert r'\n' to '\n' in python?

Tags: python, string, escaping, rawstring

Let's say I have a raw string like `r'\n'` that corresponds to `'\\n'`. Is there a way to interpret the raw string as the "normal" string `'\n'` with the line break meaning?

Comment: `r'\n'.replace("\\n", "\n")`?

Comment: Maybe a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-do-i-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string-in-python ?

Comment: Note that there is no such thing as a "raw string" in Python - there is only a "raw string literal".  `a=r'\n'; b='\\n'` ... leaves `a` and `b` with identical contents.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew : You can vote to close with that as duplicate you know.

Comment: @MartinBonner I voted to close as unclear. As it is both unclear, and seems to be a dupe.

Comment: Ah!  Fair enough.  Well, he's got one of each now.

Answer (score 0):

You can get a newline by `r'\n'.replace("\\n", "\n")`