# How do I unescape characters in python 3.6?

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, web-crawler

I'm a little confused on how to unescape characters in python. I am parsing some HTML using BeautifulSoup, and when I retrieve the text content it looks like this:

```
\u00a0\n\n\n\r\nState-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA.\u00a0\r\n\n\n\r\nOutstanding support
```

I'd like for it to look like this:

```
State-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA. Outstanding support
```

Here is my code below:

```
    self.__page = requests.get(url)
    self.__soup = BeautifulSoup(self.__page.content, "lxml")
    self.__page_cleaned = self.__removeTags(self.__page.content) #remove script and style tags
    self.__tree = html.fromstring(self.__page_cleaned) #contains the page html in a tree structure
    page_data = {}
    page_data["content"] =  self.__tree.text_content()
```

How do I remove those encoded backslashed characters? I've looked everywhere and nothing has worked for me.

Comment: how do you know that the content looks like this? do you print it or save it to a file or?

Comment: I do both and it comes out like that

Comment: Is that what you get when you do `print(page_data["content"])`? Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?

Comment: Yes, and I'm using python 3

Comment: Can you please do `print(repr(page_data["content"]))` and paste the output into your question?

Comment: Can you provide a snippet that includes your input data (`__page.content`) so that I can copy it to my editor and see myself?

Comment: 'need for tech savvy or prior experience.\xa0\n\xa0\n\n\n\n\xa0'

Comment: my data is as follows: self.__page = requests.get(url) it's just a get request to a page

Comment: I updated my code snippets in the original post

Comment: Are you saying that the stuff in the top code block is what you get when you do `print(repr(page_data["content"]))`?

Comment: Yes that's correct PM 2Ring

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use regular expressions:

```
import re

s = '\u00a0\n\n\n\r\nState-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA.\u00a0\r\n\n\n\r\nOutstanding support'
s = ' '.join(re.findall(r"[\w%\-.']+", s))

print(s) #output: State-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA. Outstanding support
```

[re.findall("exp", s)](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.findall) returns a list of all substrings of s which match the pattern "exp". In the case of "[\w]+" all combinations of letters or numbers (no hex string like "\u00a0"):

```
['State', 'of', 'the', 'art', 'security', 'and', '100', 'uptime', 'SLA', 'Outstanding', 'support']
```

You can include characters by adding them to the expression like so:

```
re.findall(r"[\w%.-']+", s)    # added "%", "." and "-" ("-"needs to be escaped by "\")
```

' '.join(s) returns a string of all elements seperated by the string in the quotes (in this case a space).

Comment: Thanks man that worked, can you explain what's going on? Also, I didn't want to remove the slashes so I don't need that part. I will see what other solutions can be offered before I accept your answer

Comment: `s = '\u00a0\n\n\n\r\nState-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA.\u00a0\r\n\n\n\r\nOutstanding support'` isn't the data shown in the question. That's just normal text. You should be using a raw string to put those backslash sequences into your code as a literal string.

Answer (score 3):

You can convert those escape sequences to proper text using the `codecs` module.

```
import codecs

s = r'\u00a0\n\n\n\r\nState-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA.\u00a0\r\n\n\n\r\nOutstanding support'

# Convert the escape sequences
z = codecs.decode(s, 'unicode-escape')
print(z)
print('- ' * 20)

# Remove the extra whitespace
print(' '.join(z.split()))
```

**output**

```
    [several blank lines here]
 



State-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA. 



Outstanding support
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - 
State-of-the-art security and 100% uptime SLA. Outstanding support
```

The `codecs.decode(s, 'unicode-escape')` function is quite versatile. It can handle simple backslash escapes, like those newline and carriage return sequences (`\n` and `\r`), but its main strength is handling Unicode escape sequences, like the `\u00a0`, which is just a nonbreak space char. But if your data had other Unicode escapes in it, like those for foreign alphabetic chars or emojis, it would handle them too.

---

As Evpok mentions in a comment, this *won't* work if the text string contains actual Unicode characters as well as Unicode `\u` or `\U` escape sequences.

From the [codecs docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#text-encodings):

> **unicode_escape**
>
> Encoding suitable as the contents of a Unicode literal in
>   ASCII-encoded Python source code, except that quotes are not escaped.
>   Decodes from Latin-1 source code. Beware that Python source code
>   actually uses UTF-8 by default.

Also see the docs for [`codecs.decode`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#codecs.decode).

Comment: This fails with strings containing unicode characters since `unicode-escape` assumes latin1 input

Comment: @Evpok Good point! I've updated my answer. I must admit that a text string containing a mix of Unicode chars & Unicode escape sequences would be rather strange, but I guess I've seen all sorts of strangely mangled Unicode. ;) At least Python 3 is a lot better in that regard than Python 2.

Comment: It actually bit me while trying to unescape `"l\'œil"`, which doesn't escape unicode, but still has escapes.

Comment: @Evpok If that's a literal string in your Python script, then it doesn't need unescaping. OTOH, if that's data you've read in, so you actually have `r"l\'œil"`, which is equivalent  to `"l\\'œil"`, then yes, `unicode-escape` decoding won't help. There are some suggestions at https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885181/4014959 but some of those answers only apply to Python 2.

Comment: Yes, thank you, the ast solution there was actually what I ended up using :-)