# Proper way to de-escape a string with an escaped colon ":" in python 3.6

Tags: python, escaping, python-3.6, compatibility, properties-file

I am attempting to write a python script that converts a .properties file (as read by Ant), and converts the result into a dictionary, mapping keys to values.

As part of the process (using configparser.RawConfigParser), I discovered that .properties files have their values escaped, and I decided to follow the top result to try and de-escape them (see [How do I un-escape a backslash-escaped string in python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1885181/936083)).  As I am using python 3 (specifically, python 3.6), I use `value = value.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')` to un-escape the string.

This was all working well, until I came across a Windows path, which was escaped like `r'C\:\\Path\\to\\something'`, note the colon is escaped.  While attempting to resolve this, I decided to consult [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.escape), only to find that in the latest python (3.7), re.escape does NOT escape `:`.  However, python 3.6 does.  This leads me to start questioning language compatibility:

1. Does `r'\:'.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')` return `':'` or `r'\:'` in python 3.7?
2. How can I handle de-escaping colons in python 3, without needing to worry about version?  If I follow up the decode with `value = value.replace(r'\:', ':')`, I don't want it to erroneously replace values.
3. Is this a bug that was fixed in python 3.7?

Comment: `r` has nothing to do with `re.escape`. One is a prefix for string literals in your source code, and means that backslashes in that literal are backslashes, not escape sequences. The other takes a string value and escapes anything needed to use that string value in a literal expression without treating any of its characters as special regex characters.

Comment: @abarnert, I know, it stands for 'raw', I'm merely using raw strings to easily show my meaning that every backslash is escaped.  However, there is no standard library way of de-escaping a string , and re-escape seems to be the most related thing in the standard library, and I thought there could be consistency there (perhaps not, could be part of the answer).