# python with hex string change \u0026 to &

Tags: python, hex

I have a string like this:

```
downloadFile":"/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996\u0026stepNo=0\u0026resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav
```

I need to change \u0026 (which is hex) to & 
I even tried this -->

```
.replace("\u0026","&")
```

it didnt work

Comment: Please show your attempt at this. Using that same code I get the correct result.

Comment: I guess the original input is something like `a = "\\u0026"`, with 2 backslashes to input a real "\", and OP is asking for a reverse function of `re.escape`. However I can't find a good solution.

Comment: If my guess is right, then all the answer at this time are wrong, since if we enter `a = "\u0026"` then `a` is now "&", a normal escape, no need to convert.

Answer (score 2):

As my comment said, I guess the "\u0026" is an **escaped** string.

That is, the real input should be something like

```
a = "\\u0026"
```

with double backslashes to enter a real "\".

Then, we may use `json.loads` as a tricky reverse function for `re.escape`, for example:

```
import json
json.loads("{\"downloadFile\":\"/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996\\u0026stepNo=0\\u0026resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav\"}")
# output: 
# {'downloadFile': '/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996&stepNo=0&resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav'}
```

Or wrap it into a function:

```
def deescape(escaped):
    return str(json.loads("{\"s\":\"" + escaped + "\"}"))[7 : -2]

deescape("\\u0026") # return '&'
```

**Update:** This solution is not suitable if `escaped` contains ":". The real solution [should be](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181):

```
# Python 2
def deescape(escaped)
    return escaped.decode('string_escape')

# Python 3
def deescape(escaped)
    return escaped.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
```

Answer (score 1):

When it comes to URLs, make you a favor and use `urllib`, here you need [`urllib.parse.unquote`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.unquote)

```
import urllib.parse

url = "/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996\u0026stepNo=0\u0026resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav"
print(urllib.parse.unquote(url))
```

---

*If it's Python2.x, use `import urllib` and `urllib.unquote()`.*

Answer (score 1):

From what I can see there appear to be quotation marks on the colon sign after `downloadFile` which could be causing an error. You could escape them using a backslash (`\`) like so:

```
yourVar = "downloadFile\":\"/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996\u0026stepNo=0\u0026resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav"
yourVar.replace("\u0026","&")
```

Optionally you could define the variable with single quotes, as this could allow your current string to work since the double quote around the colon would be ignored:

```
yourVar = 'downloadFile":"/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996\u0026stepNo=0\u0026resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav'
yourVar.replace("\u0026","&")
```

[For reference I have added what I ran in my console since the code worked fine for me](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UG1oP.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try this code:

```
downloadFile ="/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996\u0026stepNo=0\u0026resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav"

print(downloadFile.replace("\u0026","&"))
```

**Output :**

```
/myportal/ABC/35/audio/182/audio?Id=996&stepNo=0&resource=996-0-dde82d48-3097-4835-a1e4-30602c460fd7-1.wav
```

Answer (score 0):

None worked the only thing that worked for me is by using --> \u0026  note double \

```
myStr.replace("\\u0026","&")
```

Answer (score 0):

I just ran in to this issue and slightly adjusted [the code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53961421/6045800) that [Geno Chen](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9035237/geno-chen) provided which worked for me. The function I used was:

```
def deescape(escaped):
return escaped.encode().decode('unicode_escape').encode().decode("utf-8", "replace")
```

I used it inside of a lambda function to apply this to all records inside a pandas series.