# Create raw unicode character from hex string representation/enter single backslash

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, unicode, backslash

I want to create a raw unicode character from a string hex representation. That is, I have a string s = '\u0222' which will be the 'Ȣ' character.

Now, this works if I do

```
>>> s = '\u0222'
>>> print(s)
'Ȣ'
```

but, if I try to do concatenation, it comes out as

```
>>> h = '0222'
>>> s = r'\u' + '0222'
>>> print(s)
\u0222
>>> s
'\\u0222'
```

because as it can be seen, what's actually in string is '\\u' not '\u'. How can I create the unicode character from hex strings or, how can I enter a true single backslash?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Entering `\u0222` is only for string constants and the Python interpreter generates a single Unicode code point for that syntax.  It's not meant to be constructed manually.  The `chr()` function is used to generate Unicode code points.  The following works for strings or integers:

```
>>> chr(int('0222',16)) # convert string to int base 16
'Ȣ'
>>> chr(0x222)          # or just pass an integer.
'Ȣ'
```

And FYI `ord()` is the complementary function:

```
>>> hex(ord('Ȣ'))
'0x222'
```

Comment: Much better answer. I figured there was something that did this but I didn't know what it was.

Answer (score 3):

This was a lot harder to solve than I initially expected:

```
code = '0222'
uni_code = r'\u' + code
s = uni_code.encode().decode('unicode_escape')
print(s)
```

Or

```
code = b'0222'
uni_code = b'\u' + code
s = uni_code.decode('unicode_escape')
print(s)
```

Comment: Agreed, much harder than it looked. You beat me to it while i was testing! For OP, more detail and examples can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49754538/7835267)

Comment: It's harder because building Unicode escape constants is not the most direct route.  See the `chr()` function.