# Python: how to parse a str to a char?

Tags: python, string, char, string-parsing

Python read a str `'\\x0f'` which is 4 chars(`'\\', 'x', '0' and 'f'`) but indeed I want to express it as one char which is `'\x0f'`, is any way convert str '`\\x0f'` to char `'\x0f'`? Similarly, like converting '`\\b'` to `'\b'`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to un-escape a backslash-escaped string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-to-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string)

Comment: `'\\x0f'` is actually `'\x0f'`, there is no need to convert it. Try `print('\\x0f')` and you will see the console print out `'\x0f'`.

Comment: @mousetail [How to un-escape a backslash-escaped string?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-to-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string) answers my question, thanks!