# Python - Treat raw string (from file) as code written string

Tags: python

I'm reading a line from a file, which represents a string. 
I.E reading from file: `\'\\000\\000\\000\\000\'`.
When printing the text from the file, python prints `\'\\000\\000\\000\\000\'` (without considering the \ etc.).

But when writing this text explicitly on the code and then printing it, python prints `'\000\000\000\000'` (as expected).

I want to convert the string from the file to be treated as if it was explicitly written in the code (I'm not sure about the definitions). I tried to decode it but it changes the text entirely (adds few more slashes etc.)

```
with open('f.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline() # line is written on the file \'\\000\\000\\000\\000\'
    print(line) # prints \'\\000\\000\\000\\000\'
    explicit_line = "\'\\000\\000\\000\\000\'"
    print(explicit_line) # prints '\000\000\000\000'
    # I would like print(line) to print the same content as print(explicit_line)
```

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Does this help? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-to-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe you can try `str.decode('unicode-escape')`

Full code:

```
with open('f.txt', 'r') as f:
    line = f.readline() # line is written on the file \'\\000\\000\\000\\000\'

    print(line.encode('latin1').decode('unicode-escape')) # !!! here is the key point!!!

    print(line)
    explicit_line = "\'\\000\\000\\000\\000\'"
    print(explicit_line)
```

`str.encode('latin1')`is required here for converting `str` to `bytes` first, or you can't use  `decode('unicode-escape')`

Answer (score 1):

You can try python raw string which doesn't escape backslash

`print(r'\\0000...')`

```
raw_str = r'\abc\\a\\000'
print(raw_str)
```

```
\abc\\a\\000
```

Comment: I cannot use raw because the string is coming from a file and I'm using it through a variable

Comment: Can you add a small code snippet so your situation is better realized?

Comment: Yeah sure, added.