# Un-escape spaces with Python pathlib

Tags: python

I read Python `pathlib` is supposed to make cross-platform code easier, but it's not recognizing backslash escaped spaces.  I could work around this manually with `str.replace()`, but what's the most Pythonic way to handle it?  For example, I want the user to drag a file onto the terminal:

```
from pathlib import Path
instr = input('Drag a file here: ').strip()
infile = Path(instr)
print(infile.exists())
```

This code doesn't work if the input path has a space in it because macOS automatically adds the backslash escape when you drag a file onto the Terminal:

```
 % python3 test.py
Drag a file here: /Users/Shared/folder\ one/file1 
False
```

Someone suggested that this is duplicate of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-to-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string), but none of those answers are sufficient.  I already acknowledged that this can be done manually, but I was hoping for a Pythonic method using `pathlib`.

1. The first answer is for Python 2, but can be modified for Python 3 based on ChristopheD's comment:

```
instr.encode('utf-8').decode('unicode_escape')
```

With my given example, this produces `'/Users/Shared/folder\\ one/file1'` which fails the `Path.exists()` test.

2. The second answer raises a SyntaxError due to the forward slash.

```
ast.literal_eval(instr)
```

3. The third and fourth answers are very similar to the first, and they produces the same result:

```
decode(encode(instr, 'latin-1', 'backslashreplace'), 'unicode-escape')
```

Comment: @CharlesDuffy thank for that tip.  It works using `Path(shlex.split(instr)[0])`.  You could write that as an answer, because none of the suggestions on the other question work here.

Comment: @ElliotB, since you've confirmed that that answers your question, I'll remove the other duplicate from the list, leaving only the one that already has answers describing the `shlex` module.