Need help in pydantic class output
how to solve this pydantic validation issue?
An error occurred while processing your query:
2 validation errors for Answer
answer.TableData
Input should be a valid dictionary or instance of TableData [type=model_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/model_type
answer.str
Input should be a valid string [type=string_type, input_value=None, input_type=NoneType]
For further information visit https://errors.pydantic.dev/2.7/v/string_type <class 'str'>

here is my pydantic class which I am using for extracting data from LLM response:
def fix_json_string(input_str):
    # Manually escape backslashes first
    escaped_str = input_str.replace("\\", "\\\\")
    # Escape other problematic characters
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("\n", "\\n")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("\r", "\\r")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("\t", "\\t")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace('"', '\\"')
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("[", "\\[")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("]", "\\]")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("(", "\\(")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace(")", "\\)")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("^", "\\^")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("$", "\\$")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("*", "\\*")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("+", "\\+")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("?", "\\?")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("|", "\\|")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace(".", "\\.")
    escaped_str = escaped_str.replace("'", "\\'")
    return escaped_str


class TableData(BaseModel):
    # data: Optional[Dict[str, List[Any]]]
    data: Union[Dict[str, List[Any]], List[Dict[str, Any]]]
    answer: Optional[str]

    @classmethod
    def from_json(cls, json_str):
        try:
            fixed_json_str = fix_json_string(json_str)
            data = json.loads(fixed_json_str)  # Ensure the string is valid JSON
            return cls(**data)
        except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
            print(f"JSON decode error: {e}")
            return None
        except ValidationError as e:
            print(f"Validation error: {e}")
            return None


    class Answer(BaseModel):
        answer: Union[TableData, str] = Field
        sql: Union[str, Any] = Field
    
        @classmethod
        def from_json(cls, json_str):
            try:
                fixed_json_str = fix_json_string(json_str)
                data = json.loads(fixed_json_str)  # Ensure the string is valid JSON
                return cls(**data)
            except json.JSONDecodeError as e:
                print(f"JSON decode error: {e}")
                return None
            except ValidationError as e:
                print(f"Validation error: {e}")
                return None


No one can help you with a validation error if they don't know what the data being validated is. Share some input data.

Also, you can try this code instead of manually unescaping those backslashes. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1885181/how-to-un-escape-a-backslash-escaped-string
